# Shell script -How to group test file records based on column value and send email to corresponding receipents.?

Tags: bash, shell, unix

I have a comma separated csv file named "file1" with below details and the headers are.. incident number, date, person name and email id. The requirement is to group records by person name and send email listing all records by his or her name.

So in this example Sam, Mutthu, Andrew, Jordan will receive one email each and in that email they will see all records on their name.

> 10011,5-Jan,Sam,Sam@companydomain.com
>
> 10023,8-Jan,Mutthu,Mutthu@companydomain.com
>
> 10010,8-Jan,Mutthu,Mutthu@companydomain.com
>
> 10026,15-Jan,Sam,Sam@companydomain.com
>
> 10050,10-Jan,Jordan,Jordan@companydomain.com
>
> 10021,12-Jan,Andrew,Andrew@companydomain.com

I have searched the forum for solution but not able to map which solution to go with, all I can find below command to create separate files based in person name which will not fit in our requirement.

```
    awk -F\, '{print>$3}' file1
```

talking about our existing script, it sends email one by one using below command so it will send multiple emails to Mutthu and Sam which we don't want.

```
    /usr/sbin/sendmail -v $MAILTO $MAILCC |grep Sent >> "$HOME/maillog.txt"
```

Any Help will be appreciated

Thanks
Shan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the question is tagged "bash", here a possible solution as a pure shell script. Note that this was not tested.

```sh
#!/bin/bash

MAILCC=x@y.com

in_file="file1"

# 1. grep all lines containing a '@' (contained in email address)
# 2. Cut field 4 (the email address)
# 3. sort uniq (remove duplicate email addresses)
#
# Loop over that list
#
for email in $(grep '@' $in_file | cut -d, -f 4 | sort -u); do
    # only if $email is a non-empty string
    if [ -n "$email" ]; then
        # grep for email in source file and mail found lines
        {
            echo "From: sender@example.net"
            echo "To: $email"
            echo "Subject: Your test file records"
            echo ""
            grep "$email"  $in_file | while read -r line; do
               echo "$line"
           done
        } | /usr/sbin/sendmail -v $email $MAILCC
    fi
done | grep Send >>"$HOME/maillog.txt"
```

Comment: Thanks Ralf, its works but I cant figure out how to add subject line, to, from and other fields' also is ti possible to add html formatting?

Comment: @Shan I'm not a sendmail expert, but see my update. I don't know how to properly create a html mail.

Comment: ,@Ralf, with your update I can insert html tags with no problem...but the basic problem is that it send all records in single line even if the source file have line break, for example in my above data structure, Muthu is receiving one email with 2 records on his name which is fine  but everything is displaying in single line like below, there should be line break after his email id so that I can insert html tags on right places.
10023,8-Jan,Mutthu,Mutthu@companydomain.com 10010,8-Jan,Mutthu,Mutthu@companydomain.com

can this be fixed?

Comment: @Shan See update, now you are able do add additional `echo` commands before/after `echo "$line"`.

Comment: thanks this also work for me, sorry for replying so late as I didn't get time to spend on this.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an Awk script which does what you request.  We collect the input into an array, where each element contains the lines for one recipient, and the key is the recipient's email address (`$4`).  Finally we loop over the keys and send one message each.

```
awk -F , '{ a[$4] = a[$4] ORS $0 }
    END {
        for (user in a) {
            cmd = "/usr/sbin/sendmail -v " $4
            print "From: sender@example.net" | cmd
            print "To: " $4 | cmd
            print "Subject: stuff from CSV" | cmd
            # Neck between headers and email body
            print "" | cmd
            # Skip initial ORS
            print substr(a[user],2) | cmd
            close(cmd) } }' file.csv |
grep Sent >>"$HOME/maillog.txt"
```

I can't guess what's in `MAILCC` so I just left it off. If you always want to Cc: a static address, adding that back should be easy.

Comment: Thanks triplee, this wrok as I was looking for but mow I am struggling with html formatting of the email because it send the data as is and I have not control so I have to make a html formatted inpute file to make it wok...Is it possible if I can format the email before sending like font, table and other stuff?

if not then at least where i can define a variable and later use it? because I need to extart the first name from email and then display it in email body as first letter uppcase so "john@doamin .com" should give me John

Comment: Sure it is, but that's essentially a separate question. You need to add `Content-type: text/html` to the message headers. Accept one of the answers here (or write one of your own and accept that if you prefer) and ask a new question if you can't figure out the HTML part.

Comment: okay yes you are right, i will put it as a separate question, thanks for your help again.

Comment: i have asked a separate question so sharing the link with you just in case it falls into your area of expertise
  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54631578/shell-script-send-html-formatted-email-while-inside-an-array