# Shell Script : Send html formatted email while inside an array

Tags: html, arrays, linux, email, sendmail

I am trying to send html formatted email via shell script while reading a tab separated text file in array and need some help. I can see there were multiple similar question on forum and I also have multiple working scripts which can send html emails but I am not able to fit that code when I am inside an array.

apart form this I also need to use a variable and later use it but cant fit it inside my code, for example i have below code to extract first name and make the first letter uppercase but not sure how to merge it in my existing code.

```
 SplitName=$(echo firstname.lastname@domainname.com| cut -d'.' -f 1)
 Firstname=`echo -e $SplitName | sed -r 's/\<./\U&/g'`
```

below is my main code and data file and is working fine and creates a html formatted email but the problem is when it reads "print substr(a[user], 2) | cmd" it looses all formatting so the email I receive do have html formatting at start but not when it show me the records I need.

Any help will be appreciated .

Here is my data file

```
10011,5-Jan,Sam,Sam@companydomain.com

10023,8-Jan,Mutthu,Mutthu@companydomain.com

10010,8-Jan,Mutthu,Mutthu@companydomain.com

10026,15-Jan,Sam,Sam@companydomain.com

10050,10-Jan,Jordan,Jordan@companydomain.com

10021,12-Jan,Andrew,Andrew@companydomain.com
```

Here is my code

```
awk -F '\t'  '{ a[$4] = a[$4] ORS $0 }
 END {

 for (user in a) {
           cmd = "/usr/sbin/sendmail -v " $4
        print "From: static.name@domain.com" | cmd
        print "To: " $4 | cmd
        print "Cc: static.name@domain.com"  | cmd
        print "Subject: Some text here " $2 " Some more text"| cmd
        print "MIME-Version: 1.0" | cmd
        print "Content-Type: text/html" | cmd
        print "Content-Disposition: inline" | cmd
        print "<font face=Calibri><font size=2>Some text here<br><br>"| cmd
        print substr(a[user], 2) | cmd
                close(cmd) } }' myfile | grep Sent >>"$HOME/maillog.txt"
```

Below code is to generate html table

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
table, th, td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>


<table style="width:100%">
  <tr>
    <th>Number</th>
    <th>Date</th> 
    <th>Name</th>
  </tr>

<tr>
    <td>10011</td>
    <td>5-Jan</td>
    <td>Mutthu</td>
  </tr>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

please refer below link for more details. 
[Shell script -How to group test file records based on column value and send email to corresponding receipents.?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54310333/shell-script-how-to-group-test-file-records-based-on-column-value-and-send-emai)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need an empty line between the email headers and the body; and you need to add HTML formatting to the table in order for it to render correctly.  Something like this, perhaps:

```
# -F ',' -- sample is comma-separated, not tab-separated
awk -F ','  '{ a[$4] = a[$4] ORS "<tr><td>" $1 "</td><td>" $2 "</td><td>" $3 "</td><td>" $4 "</td></tr" }
                                 # ^^ Notice the addition of HTML
 END {
     for (user in a) {
            cmd = "/usr/sbin/sendmail -v " $4
            print "From: static.name@domain.com" | cmd
            # Send to user, not to $4
            print "To: " user | cmd
            print "Cc: static.name@domain.com"  | cmd
            # What should $2 expand to here?
            # Maybe collect that in a separate array
            print "Subject: Some text here " $2 " Some more text"| cmd
            print "MIME-Version: 1.0" | cmd
            print "Content-Type: text/html" | cmd
            # Not really useful, but why not
            print "Content-Disposition: inline" | cmd
            # Add an empty line
            print "" | cmd
            print "<font face=Calibri><font size=2>Some text here<br><br>"| cmd
            print "<table><tbody>" | cmd
            print substr(a[user], 2) | cmd
            print "</tbody></table>" | cmd
            close(cmd) } }' myfile
```

I kept this simple to highlight the general structure. You can add more embellished HTML formatting to your heart's content once you understand how this works.

Comment: I have added embellished HTML per my need and it looks good now the only think I am stuck is

1. not able to insert <a herf tag below as it did not work, without it everything is working fine, my URL is in $5.
    awk -F '\t'  '{ a[$4] = a[$4] ORS "<tr><td><a herf="$5">" $1 "</a></td><td>" $2 "</td><td>" $3 "</td><td>" $4 "</td><td>" $5 "</td></tr>" }
2. As I indicated in my post, where can I put the variable and use it when needed?..... I know point 1 is a new question and I can ask it separately.

Comment: You seem to have misspelled `href`, and you need to backslash-escape any literal eouble quotes you want to print. As you can see, you can't really put code in comments; maybe use something like https://pastebin.com/ to link to code excerpts.

Comment: It's still not clear to me where the variable is supposed to come from, or what you want to extract from `$2`. You can easily port your `cut` + `sed` code to something like `first = $4; sub(/\..*/,"", first); Firstname = toupper(substr(first,1,1)) substr(first,2)`

Comment: Well the variable issue is now sorted, my plan is to split the email id which was at $4 but I have figured out another way and its working fine.

But.. I don't know what happened exactly but STRANGELY the code is not sending email to more than one person today, when I put my email Id for all records, it sends all records to me but when I put some other person name for some of the records, the code strangely send all records to him..including the one meant for me..this is really strange it was working fine till yesterday.

Comment: You can simplify debugging by taking out all the references to `cmd`.